# Problem linking MongoDB and Laravel, no response when trying my API on Postman

Tags: php, laravel, database, mongodb, postman

I'm using Laravel and homestead to host my application, so I followed the MongoDB tutorial for its integration in Laravel since I'm using both a MySQL and A MongoDB database but there's probably something pretty simple that I can't catch since i keep getting errors while trying to add a new entry in my database through PostMan.

.env :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.56.56
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

File.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;


class File extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'files';

    use HasFactory, Uuid;

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class);
    }


}
```

FileController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\File;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function show($name)
    {
        return view('file', [
            'file' => File::where('name', '=', $name)->first()
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = new File;

        $file->name = $request->name;

        $file->save();

        return response()->json(["result" => "ok"], 201);
    }

}
```

web.php :

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/file/{name}', [FileController::class, 'show']);
```

api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('files', FileController::class)->only([
    'destroy', 'show', 'store', 'update'
]);
```

database.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'dsn' => env('DB_URI', 'mongodb+srv://username:password@<atlas-cluster-uri>/myappdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'),
            'database' => 'myappdb',
        ],

    ], ...
```

This is how my MongoDB database looks like:
[image]

And this is the queries I'm entering on PostMan/web browser to both read or add a new document called Doc1:

[image]

And:

[image]

Have I set anything wrong in my config files? or is the URI wrong?

EDIT: I've tried to put this changes in my files:

.env:

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=192.168.56.56
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=mongocrud (I don't really know what name to put here to be honest)
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

database.php:

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', '192.168.56.56'),
            'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options'  => []
        ],
```

The only difference I havbe now is for my GET method:
"Attempt to read property "name" on null"

Comment: in your mongo DB configuration everything here `mongodb+srv://username:password@<atlas-cluster-uri>` is supposed to be replaced with your configuration. check step 1 and step 2 of this tutorial https://appdividend.com/2022/01/28/laravel-mongodb-crud/

Comment: hi @N69S , I've already tried this way earlier but I'm getting the same errors, unless I wrote something wrong... I edited my question to put what i wrote in my files